# How to swap char value of nodes of linkedlist in C?

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list, char, swap

I am trying to bubble sort linkedlist based on int value which I hold in char array.
I know that I need to do following steps;

```
void bubbleSort(struct Node *start) 
{ 
    int swapped, i; 
    struct Node *ptr1; 
    struct Node *lptr = NULL; 
  
    /* Checking for empty list */
    if (start == NULL) 
        return; 
  
    do
    { 
        swapped = 0; 
        ptr1 = start; 
  
        while (ptr1->next != lptr) 
        { 
            if (ptr1->data > ptr1->next->data) 
            {  
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next); 
                swapped = 1; 
            } 
            ptr1 = ptr1->next; 
        } 
        lptr = ptr1; 
    } 
    while (swapped); 
}
```

**and**

/* function to swap data of two nodes a and b*/

```
{ 
    int temp = a->data; 
    a->data = b->data; 
    b->data = temp; 
}
```

but as I said above I have created a struct with char value;

```
struct nodeForLinkedList
{
    char frequency[STRING_LEN]; **// Purpose of this is to hold int value from text file.**
    struct nodeForLinkedList *next;
};
```

```
void swap(struct nodeForLinkedList *a, struct nodeForLinkedList *b) 
{ 
    char temp = a->frequency; 
    a->frequency = b->frequency; //  atoi(b->frequency) or strtol
    b->frequency = temp; 
}
```

here I could use **atoi** function to get int value from char array. **atoi** function help me to get int value from 'frequency' array
But I don't know how to change **a->frequency** value with b->frequency value.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use one of the string or memory copying functions from the library:

```
#include <string.h>

void swap(struct nodeForLinkedList *a, struct nodeForLinkedList *b) 
{ 
    char temp[sizeof(a->frequency)];
    strcpy(temp, a->frequency);
    strcpy(a->frequency, b->frequency);
    strcpy(b->frequency, temp);
}
```

The above use of `strcpy` assumes that the `frequency` member contains a null-terminated string. You could use `memcpy` to copy the whole array regardless of null-termination:

```
#include <string.h>

void swap(struct nodeForLinkedList *a, struct nodeForLinkedList *b) 
{ 
    char temp[sizeof(a->frequency)];
    memcpy(temp, a->frequency, sizeof(temp));
    memcpy(a->frequency, b->frequency, sizeof(temp));
    memcpy(b->frequency, temp, sizeof(temp));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot.